# How can I create a good-looking responsive image gallery WITHOUT perfectly sized images?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gallery, responsive-design

I'm using Wordpress and user-uploaded images. I'm trying to build a responsive image gallery using Bootstrap but I'm running into some trouble with it:

[Picture.png http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/6838/picturehq.png](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/6838/picturehq.png)
Also find it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExdzX/), (make sure to set the output window big enough that they switch to multi-columns)

Some of the real-world challenges and some of my constraints:

- The images aren't all going to be the same size
- The images shouldn't have to all be the same size
- The gallery needs to be responsive (images can shrink/grow, can change from 2,3,4 columns etc)
- The captions may be any length, and should be auto-truncated / hidden / etc.
- I want the images to have the proper aspect ratios, e.g. no `width:100%; height:100%`
- The captions should somehow line up

**What I've Tried**

One of the tricky ways that I used to create image galleries before responsive design was to have Wordpress create two images sizes, one with a max-width and one with a max-height, both with a soft-crop, of the size I wanted the gallery thumbnails to be. When generating the gallery I would check to see which didn't overflow the bounds and then use that image for the thumbnail. The other way is to just use an image that is close to the size I want, and then set the image as a `background-url` for the containing element with position set to `center/center`. This works great for fixed-width designs, **but it doesn't work well for responsive!** :)

Plus, as far as I know with responsive design / css there is no way to set the scale of a background image. It also seems more semantically accurate to code up images using, well, an `<img>` tag instead of a `<div>` with a `background-image` set via CSS.

Without responsive design you might also have a fixed column count, so you can do a `clear:left` on every n<sup>th</sup> image to keep the weird wrap from happening. But with responsive design the column count may change from 2,3,4 etc.

Also, without responsive design you could use Javascript to loop through the images / thumbnail containers and standardize their heights. Doing this on a responsive design is not impossible, but you have to wait for the page to load completely as the heights are set as percentages to start with and may not be accurate until all the resources are loaded. Then you have to worry about what happens on a window resize or orientation change. This seems like a hack and not the right way to do it.

I also tried setting the `min-height` areas for the `.thumbnail` element and setting the `<a>` containing the image to `display:block` and setting that to have a `min-height` as well. Results are better, but still not great:

3 column:
[Picture.png http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/9472/picturemk.png](http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/9472/picturemk.png)

4 column:

[Picture 1.png http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/706/picture1uh.png](http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/706/picture1uh.png)

#### So, how can I create a good-looking responsive image gallery WITHOUT perfectly sized images?

Comment: Masonry might be what you're looking for. http://www.bluelimemedia.com/2012/04/30/jquery-masonry-and-wordpress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this *doesn't* require 'perfectly-sized images', it does, for a CSS-only solution, require specifically-sized `li` elements, with their `overflow` to `hidden` (so that the image doesn't have its ratio skewed, though it may be cropped by the parent `li` container).

Setting the `li` elements to  `float: left;` in conjunction with the defined `width` and `height` allows for a uniform presentation/distribution, with the gallery able to self-adapt and reflow according to the width of the window/parent-`ul`:

```
li {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    padding: 4px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li p {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
}

li:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo (with `float: left;`)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ExdzX/3/).

(Removed the `display: inline-block` solution, since it doesn't appear to allow descendant elements to be absolutely-positioned with regard to the `li` with that `display` property.)

If JavaScript solutions are possible, there's also [jQuery-required Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) (and [non-jQuery Masonry](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/)) and [Isotope (requires jQuery)](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), among others.

Although, if you're able to live with the restricted-width of the `li`s, and somewhat limited cross-browser support <sup>[*compatibility*](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t410)</sup>, you could use CSS columns:

```
ul {
    -moz-column-width: 160px;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    -ms-column-width: 160px;
    -ms-column-gap: 0;
    -o-column-width: 160px;
    -o-column-gap: 0;
    -webkit-column-width: 160px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    column-width: 160px;
    column-gap: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ExdzX/2/).

Comment: +1 - looks pretty good, although I'm not crazy about defining the sizes of the `li` elements. i like your hover transition on the labels.

Comment: Yeah; the `column` approach reduces the need for specific sizes, but unfortunately it's not that well-supported, currently. And I did forget to implement cross-browser transitions. ...oops! XD

Comment: (Edited the answer to include cross-browser vendor-prefixed transtitions, and to remove the [non-working `display: inline-block` suggestion](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ExdzX/4/).)